# Clang diagnostics and clang-check differs in warning count

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang, diagnostics, clang-static-analyzer

For the following snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum index{
    one = 5,
    two,
    three,
    four,
    five
};

int fun(){
    int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
    int i = arr[index::one];
    printf("%d\n", i);
    int j = arr[index::four];   
    printf("%d\n", j);
    return 0;
}
```

Clang diagnostic reports two warnings (which is actually correct)
whereas clang-check reports only one error. Also, the warning message is different in both cases.

Output:

[image]

So why clang diagnostic is able to find out all warnings but not clang-check?